# Дополнение класса полями, в зависимости от версии входящих данных

Tags: c++, ооп, архитектура, наследование, шаблоны-проектирования

Реализовываю программу, где класс имеет разные версии, в зависимости от которой он дополняется полями. Ниже пример кода:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    int i;

public:
    A() {}
    A(int _i) : i(_i) {}

    virtual void print()
    {
        cout << "A obj, i = " << i << "!\n";
    }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    string str;

public:
    B() {}
    B(int _i, string _str) : A(_i), str(_str) {}

    void print() override
    {
        A::print();
        cout << "B obj, str = " << str << "!\n";
    }
};

A *make_obj(stringstream& ss)
{
    A *result(NULL);
    int version;
    ss >> version;

    switch (version)
    {
    case 1:
        int i;
        ss >> i;
        result = new A(i);
        break;
    case 2:
    {
        int i;
        ss >> i;
        string str;
        ss >> str;
        result = new B(i, str);
    }
    break;
    default:
        cout << "Error!";
        break;
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    stringstream ser_obj_a;
    ser_obj_a << 1 << " " << 1337; //version: 1, i = 1337;
    stringstream ser_obj_b;
    ser_obj_b << 2 << " " << 2674 << " " << "Hello"; //version: 2, i = 2674, str = "Hello";
    
    auto *a = make_obj(ser_obj_a);
    auto *b = make_obj(ser_obj_b);
    a->print();
    cout << "=================\n";
    b->print();
    
}
```

Результатом работы которого является:

```
A obj, i = 1337!
=================
A obj, i = 2674!
B obj, str = Hello!
```

Но проблема заключается в том, что для отдельной работы с полями класса, мне придётся использовать приведение типов, тот же dynamic_cast. А так же всегда передавать указатель на объект в методе, причём с базовым типом.

Вопрос: существуют ли какие-нибудь паттерны, которые помогают решению подобной проблемы в с++ с дополнением класса полями или какие-нибудь "обёртки", которые упрощают процесс работы с этим? Рассматривал вариант с использованием reference_wrapper, но это больше на костыль похоже будет.

Comment: При передаче объекта по значению, вам пришлось бы писать собственный стек с идентификатором типа элемента. Просто не выйдет, так как разные объекты имеют разный размер в байтах. Динамическое приведение типа это как раз и есть проверка какого типа объект. У вас это не проблема , а самый простой способ.